# Output bufferhas type int32 but elem_size of the buffer passed in is 1 instead of 4

Tags: c++, halide

I'm compiling a `Func` to a static library, and using it in a C program. I'm getting a message saying: `Output buffer f20 has type int32 but elem_size of the buffer passed in is 1 instead of 4`. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in this case. Here's the `Func`:

```
Var x, y, c;
Func out;
out(c, x, y) = cast<uint8_t>(255);
```

If I understand correctly, the resolved output type should be `uint8_t`. Here's how I'm creating my buffer in the C program:

```
buffer_t buffer;

buffer.extent[0] = 4;
buffer.extent[1] = width;
buffer.extent[2] = height;
buffer.elem_size = 1;
buffer.host = data;
buffer.stride[0] = 1;
buffer.stride[1] = 4;
buffer.stride[2] = stride;

fill_buffer(&buffer);
```

The buffer truly contains `uint8_t` values and I'm setting the `elem_size` to 1 so I don't understand how to make halide use it as 8 bit values..

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give an answer here other than to confirm your expectation here is correct. If you compile `out` directly in a straight forward fashion, the output buffer `elem_size` should be 1. Question is why it is going wrong. If you compile with the HL_DEBUG_CODEGEN env variable set to 2 or higher, there will be debug output showing the IR that Halide is actually compiling. (Optionally you can call `compile_to_lowered_stmt` to dump the lowered IR to a file.) This might help show why this is not working.

There is a very slim chance it is a compiler issue, but more likely there is either stale code involved or you are not calling the filter being compiled from that code snippet.